# iOS: how can I utilize multiple processor cores within a single app?

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have a computationally intensive app, and tried reducing computing times by using parallel processing. I started with GDC, but didn't reduce computing times at all. In fact, serial and concurrent queues yielded exactly the same performance. I tried it with NSThreads, still to no avail.
It is as if the application would be using 1 core only. I'd appreciate hearing from anyone who had positive results in using multi-threading to increase computational throughput.

The algorithm is in pure C, and could be partitioned nicely - no mutexes, locks required or used.

Below is my original GCD code. Results are same with 2 or 3 threads. I double checked that blocks are not executing serially - so they just run slower:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    doStuff1();
});

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    doStuff2();
});

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    doStuff3();
});

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I have never tried to do anything but to keep long tasks and I/O off the main thread to not block the user interface. If you are suspicious that the could parallelise the computation, but iOS scheduling does not allow it, you can test by running your algorithm under OS X.

Comment: Parallel processing doesn't necessarily produce reduced computation times; it just prevents the main thread from being blocked while executing the computationally expensive algorithm. If you can break up the algorithm into 'sub jobs' and then execute them in parallel, you may then achieve reduced computation times.

Comment: What are doStuff1 (), doStuff2 (), doStuff3 () doing?

Comment: doStuffX() methods execute some calculations (physics simulation) on their designated partition of data (no overlaps, no locks). They don't use any I/O or call to any services. What they use is the accelerate framework's vDSP functions though.

Answer (score 0):

I have definitely seen concurrent processing yield near-optimal results on iOS devices, i.e. 55% of the single-core time when executed on two cores. It's possible. The devil is in the details, and there aren't anywhere near enough details here for anyone to know why you're not seeing such results. There are any number of ways that your workload could be interlocked. They could be explicitly interlocked in ways you just haven't accounted for, or they could be implicitly interlocked. For instance, even if there's multiple cores, there's still only one "hard drive" so if all tasks are constantly thrashing the "disk" they could be effectively interlocked. Even though flash disks are solid-state they are not (necessarily) capable of multiple simultaneous writes. My expectation would be for disk I/O to be effectively serial-ized at one level or another.

Comment: hi, the functions don't use any I/O and work on their own segregated piece of data - they just execute arithmetic calculations on a buffer - and with pure C code. I use the vDSP framework, but I kind of ruled that out I think by replacing those calls with their equivalent pure C implementations. So I don't think there's any interlocking going on, it more looks like some throttling or core affinity issues.

Comment: Not sure what to say... I've seen concurrent processing definitively work on iOS, as have many others, so there's obviously something weird going on in your particular case, but without more info, no one could possibly say.